# compute mean using std::accumulate fails

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to compute the mean value of a vector of doubles using the following code (compiled with `g++ mean.cc -std=c++0x`):

```
// mean.cc

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Mean {
  unsigned int n;
  Mean(unsigned int n) : n(n) {}
  double operator()(double sum, double x) {
    return sum + x/n;
  }
};

int main () {
  std::vector<double> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  Mean mean(v.size());
  std::cout << "mean: " << std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, mean) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The mean value should be `3.5`, I think. The program however prints `mean: 1`.

If I remove the division by `n` in my `operator()` the sum of the elements is computed as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that gcc uses `accumulate<vector<double>::iterator,int>` instead of `accumulate<vector<double>::iterator,double>`. If you use the specific template values it will work:

```
cout << "mean: " << accumulate<vector<double>::iterator,double>(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, mean) << endl;
```

**EDIT**: This happens because the type `T` in `template< class InputIterator, class T >
T accumulate` is defined by your initial value `0`, which is an integer. So use the line above or

```
cout << "mean: " << accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0, mean) << endl;
```

#### References

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/accumulate/

Comment: Or just pass the initial value as `0.0`. I’d prefer that: less code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks, just noticed that myself and updated my answer.

Comment: @NeilKirk: The question was edited, probably to provide a compiling example. However, the error was fixed at the same time. Reproduced the original scenario in the question.