# Using a template Lambda expression inside a std::accumulate c++?

Tags: c++, std, lambda, accumulate

Is there to templatize the "ints" in the lambda function below in the case that there was a standard container of doubles or floats, etc.?  I have searched the world over for help with this.  I even asked for the help of my professor who says it is possible but is to cryptic about the answer.

```
template <typename T>
   float mean(T &container)
   {
     auto sum = std::accumulate(container.begin(), container.end(), 0/*initial value*/,
     [](int total, int cur)
     {
          return total+cur;
     }//end of lambda
   );//end of accumulate
   return static_cast<float>(sum) / container.size(); //to find the mean
}//end of mean
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there words missing from that first sentence?

Comment: Yes there is, sorry.  Is there [a way] to templatize...

Answer (score 1):

There is typically a way to get the type of the contained data from a container.

For e.g you could replace the `int`s in that function with `T::value_type` which should support all containers which expose such a typedef.

This wont work for types such as `map` but you can specialize for it if you want to support them.

Comment: Thanks! I have figured a way around it that works okay. It just forces the function call to look something like this.
float initialValue = 0.0;
mean(container, initialValue);
Then I added an extra template value to catch the data type of initialValue.

Answer (score -1):

But it seems to me that writing such a function that way may induce loss of data
For example

```
std::vector<float> vf;
vf.push_back(1.3);
vf.push_back(1.5);
vf.push_back(1.3);
vf.push_back(1.123);
vf.push_back(1.526);
float m=mean(vf);
```

will always return 1

The answer here >>> [compute mean using std::accumulate fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599552/compute-mean-using-stdaccumulate-fails) in the Edit part is not really true as if I change `vf.push_back(1.3);` into `vf.push_back(3.3);` I'll obtain the wished result.